# Appear the digits in the number $3^{3^{3^3}}$ approximately equally often?

Tags: number-theory, decimal-expansion, tetration

Does the number

$$3\uparrow \uparrow 4 = 3^{3^{3^3}}$$

contain the digits 0-9 approximately equally often ?

With "approximately" I mean that a chi-squared test for 
equal distribution would produce no value greater than 17 
(about the critical value at the 5%-level).

Is it necessary to calculate the number to find that out, or is there
a better way ?

It is relatively easy to calculate the last digits of such big numbers, but is there a method also for the first ones ?

Comment: This number "only" has roughly 12 trillion bits; it wouldn't be hard (in the abstract) to calculate it and find out...

Comment: I checked the frequences of 0-9 in the first million digits of $3\uparrow \uparrow4$. Here the result : [99669, 100615, 100299, 99697, 99968, 99776, 99853, 99673, 99942, 100508]. So, the first million digits are very well equally distributed.

Comment: For the last million digits I got : [100285, 99774, 100141, 100192, 100189, 99898, 100299, 99331, 100263, 99628] , also a very well equally distribution.

Comment: Consider splitting your question into several different ones, the last question there should likely stand on its own.

Comment: A related problem is to determine whether $0.392781…$ (formed of the increasing sequence of powers of $3$) is normal to base $10$. According to Yann Bugeaud (p. 97 in _Distribution Modulo One and Diophantine Approximation_), such a problem (with the powers of $2$ instead of the powers of $3$) is still unsolved.

Comment: Did you see [this](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/172833) question on MO?